# I have defined char[] b_arr = new char[b.length()]; and it shows an warning assignment value is never used

Tags: java, arrays, warnings

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
// code skipped
char[] b_arr  = new char[b.length()];
// ^^^^^ IDE complains on this line
b_arr = b.toCharArray();
// code skipped
```

IDE complain on `char[] b_arr  = new char[b.length()];` value of `b_arr` is not being used.

[Full version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byUUe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is correct.

```
char[] b_arr = new char[b.length()]; // here you assign a new char array to b_arr
b_arr = b.toCharArray();            // and here you already overwrite it without ever using the previous value
```

Answer (score 2):

In next line

your are assigning new array to `b_arr` so previous array's reference will be lost and never used

Note : [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) `Converts this string to a new character array.`

```
char[] b_arr = new char[b.length()];
b_arr = b.toCharArray(); // new array , lost the previous one
```

so follow the advice and do

```
char[] b_arr = b.toCharArray();
```